# Laravel 8: send Ajax (Fetch) data to Controller via POST method

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, forms, request

I'm trying to get the request data in the inside a Controller, but Laravel doesn't show nothing. In the other controllers using **GET** method I can do it easily.

I can't use page redirect in this case, so Ajax is my only option.

I've searched the entire stackoverflow and couldn't find anything that works.

My code:

`web.php`

```
Route::post('adiciona_credito', [AdicionaCreditoController::class, 'post_credito'])->name('adiciona_credito.post');
```

`AdicionaCreditoController.php`

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers\MixVirtual;

    use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
    use Exception;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;

    class AdicionaCreditoController extends Controller {
        public function post_credito(Request $request): array {
            dd(request()->all()); // print the request
            try {
                // Saving data to the database.
                $retorno['msg']           = 'success';
            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                $retorno['msg']    = $e->getMessage();
            }
            header('Content-type: application/json;charset=utf-8');
            return $retorno;
        }
    }
```

`ajax.js`

```
document.getElementById('form_adiciona_credito').addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
    
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('X-CSRF-TOKEN', document.querySelector('[name="csrf-token"]').getAttribute('content'));

        let options = {
            method : 'POST',
            headers: headers,
            body   : JSON.stringify({
                credito      : document.getElementById('credito').value,
                justificativa: document.getElementById('justificativa').value
            })
        }

        fetch('./adiciona_credito', options).then(function(response) {
            if (!response.ok) {
                // Treating errors
            }
            response.json().then(function(return) {
                // AJAX callback
            });
        });
    }
```

`HTML` form

```
<form id="form_adiciona_credito" method="post" action="{{route('adiciona_credito.post')}}">
                    @csrf
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 my-1">
                            <input required type="number" class="form-control" id="credito" placeholder="Cr&eacute;dito para adicionar">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 my-1">
                            <textarea required class="form-control" id="justificativa" placeholder="Justificativa"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 my-1">
                            <button class="btn btn-success float-end" id="btn_adiciona_credito">Add
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Screenshot of the browser network tab:
[image]

Comment: have you tried `return response()->json($retorno);` in your controller?

Comment: I don't use the `fetch()` method myself, but if you're sending `body: JSON.stringify()`, then `$request->all()` might work if you also set the `contentType` header to `application/json`. Or maybe try `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, and `body: {credito: ..., justificativa: ...}`. You shouldn't have to use `request()->getContent()` when using Laravel as an API, but play with your request more to see if you can get `$request->all()` and `$request->input('credito')` working.

Comment: @TimLewis I understand your point, but why shouldn't I use the `request()->getContent()` in Laravel Controller? I assume it's the same aproach of the `file_get_contents('php://input')` .

Comment: @MohammadEdrisRaufi the `$retorno` variable is just to define if the request was a success or fail.

Comment: It's not a case of "shouldn't" use it; if it works, there's no reason not to. The point I was trying to make is that you shouldn't _have_ to use `$request->getContent()`. All of the documentation points to using `$request->all()`, and `$request->input(...)` to access the data being sent to the Controller. If you're ok with `->getContent()`, then go for it! But simply be aware that using that isn't typical, and you might run into other quirks and oddities later in development. Remember that as a framework, Laravel tries to simplify things for you, request IO being one of those things 

Comment: I agree. My problem was that I coudn't get the wanted result using the `request()` methods, but it worked setting the header `content-type` to `application/json`. Post an answer and I'll accept it. Thank you!